Efficiently combining sparse and dense sub matrices with R Matrix package
The following code will create a sparse matrix w and a dense matrix v and combines them horizontally.  The result is efficiently stored, preserving the sparsity in w.  Is this the best way to do this?  Will downstream computations on the combined matrix be efficient?  Note that in my ultimate application the sparse matrix will be much, much larger and will usually be larger than the dense matrix.
require(Matrix)
p <- 5; dg <- cbind(1 : p, c(1 : (p -1), NA) + 0.1)
w <- bandSparse(p, k=c(0, 1), diagonals=dg, symmetric=TRUE)
w   # 9 nonzero elements on the diagonal or upper triangle
w@x
length(w@x)   # 9; nice
# Without sparse=FALSE below, cbind(w, v) will fully expand elements originating with w
v <- Matrix((1:15)/10, 5, 3, sparse=TRUE)
length(v@x)
z <- cbind(w, v)
z
class(z)
z@x
length(z@x)  # 28; nice
p*p + 5*4    # required with sparse=FALSE


It's hard to answer without any information about the downstream operations, but I can at least say that for calls cbind(x, y), where x is formally dense and y is formally sparse, the return value is formally sparse if and only if (length(x) + nnzero(y, na.counted=TRUE))/(length(x) + length(y)) < 0.5, i.e., if and only if less than half of the elements are structurally nonzero.

Thanks; that's helpful, for reasons other than efficiency.
